# Copying Rows in For Loop and Pasting to new Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row, range

I am having problems copy/pasting rows based on criteria.

```
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
Dim Distance As Long
Distance = 14
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample Address Database")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Workspace")
lastrow1 = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
lastcolumn1 = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim L As Long
For L = 2 To lastrow1
    If _
    sh.Cells(L, Distance).Value <= CDbl(cboRadius.Value) Then
        sh.Range("A" & L & ":" & lastcolumn1 & L).Copy _
        Destination:=sh2.Range("A" & L)
    End If
Next
```

cboRadius.Value is a number from a userform (there is no problem with that line.)

Whenever I try to run this code, I get a "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed, with the yellow arrow pointing to the destination line. What is the problem?

**EDIT:**
Ed Heywood-Lonsdale suggested I change

```
sh.Range("A" & L & ":" & lastcolumn1 & L).Copy _
```

To

```
sh.Range("A" & L & ":A" & lastcolumn1 & L).Copy _
```

Now only column A, or if I change it to B, C, D, etc. is being copied. I think the problem is that it may not be registering that lastcolumn1 and L are column/row numbers and is instead making them one value, thus causing a range malfunction.

Comment: If you're trying to select the rightmost column as `lastcolumn1`, shouldn't you use `xlToRight`?

Comment: @Jack If you start in column a and go right you will go to the last column before the first blank (not always the REAL last column), but if (As the op does) you go to the VERY last cell in the worksheet then go left to the first column with data that will be the last used column.

Comment: @user2140261 Very good point. I didn't know that trick; thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just filter your data in place using the built in Excel Filters, then copy the results over instead of trying to Loop over every row.

***BUT*** If you want to loop the rows anyways:

In order to use the `Range` function you need to use column letters not column numbers.

You have 2 options here. Use

```
Chr(lastcolumn1 + 64)
```

instead of lastcolumn1. The flaw is This will only work for columns up to columns `Z`, and it won't work for double letter columns without an if statement and more code. Like the following should work for up to Column `ZZZ`

```
If lastcolumn1> 52 Then
    strColumnLetter = Chr(Int((lastcolumn1- 1) / 52) + 64) & Chr(Int((lastcolumn1- 27) / 26) + 64) & Chr(Int((lastcolumn1- 27) Mod 26) + 65)
ElseIf lastcolumn1> 26 Then
    strColumnLetter = Chr(Int((lastcolumn1- 1) / 26) + 64) & Chr(Int((lastcolumn1- 1) Mod 26) + 65)
Else
    strColumnLetter = Chr(lastcolumn1+ 64)
End If
```

But you could also use

```
strColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, lastcolumn1).EntireColumn.Address(False, False), ":")(0)
```

OR

```
strColumnLetter = Left(Replace(Cells(1, lastcolumn1).Address(1, 0), "$", ""), InStr(1, Replace(Cells(1, lastcolumn1).Address(1, 0), "$", ""), 1) - 1)
```

OR

```
strColumnLetter = Left(Cells(1, lastcolumn1).Address(1, 0), InStr(1, Cells(1, lastcolumn1).Address(1, 0), "$") - 1)
```

as that will work for as many columns as Excel will hold.

Your last option if you don't want to convert the number to the column Letter would be to get a range of Cells, as the `Cells` function CAN accept column numbers for arguments.

```
sh.Range(cells(L,1), cells(L,lastcolumn1))
```

Again I would suggest just using the standard built in filter function to filter out the data you don't want then just copy whats left though. This was just to add more options.

If you supply some sample info I could write you a sub that will do the filter copy paste for you but I don't know how your data is set up.

here is an example that should work based on your Original Question:

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim sh As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
Dim Distance As Long
Distance = 14


Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample Address Database")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Workspace")

lastrow1 = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastcolumn1 = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With sh
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).AutoFilter , _
    field:=Distance, _
    Criteria1:="<=" & CDbl(151), _
    Operator:=xlAnd

    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Copy _
    sh2.Range("A2")

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to use Ed Heywood-Lonsdale's advice but the filter idea is interesting as I'm always looking to streamline code. Here's the thing, though; I have a large database of information and I'm copying it to another sheet if it matches the right criteria. Then I'm sorting that information to keep the original database intact and to speed up searching.

Comment: @Al.Sal I have updated my answer with an example of how you would implement the Filter~>Copy~>Paste Let me know if there are any issues. Remember always run code on a COPY of your data.

Comment: @Al.Sal What exact line is it Highlighting when you click Debug?

Comment: I used your code (roughly) but the only problem I had was that the filter only worked if the active sheet was the database I'm working with (I am using a copy of course.) Also, why did you repeat .Autofilter twice?

Comment: Let me repost my lines (properly formatted this time.)  

`sh.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).AutoFilter , _
    field:=Distance, _
    Criteria1:="<=" & CDbl(cboRadius.Value), _
    Operator:=xlAnd
sh.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Copy _
    sh2.Range("A2")
`

Comment: The entire .Autofilter area was highlighted but the yellow arrow pointed to the operator.

Comment: I added With... End With and now the highlighted area is the first `sh.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(1, lastcolumn1))`.

Comment: This is odd. It only works (on other sheets) if I use `("A" & 1 & ":A" & Chr(64 + lastcolumn1) & 1)' instead of Range(Cells...) as I have a comment back. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: @Al.Sal This was a complete over look on my part and I apologize. What is happening is that the Cells command is working on the ActiveWorksheet, even though it is inside or a Range on another worksheet (thus the Error) I will update my code to account for this it was just a dead brain on my part. I have updated the code. And the double Autofilter is just something i always do because I've had issues in the past without it where the Autofilter wouldn't be activated without it being called first no idea why just a habit now.

Comment: @Al.Sal Code has been updated notice Only using the With on the sh, and I added the `.` before the cells functions.

Comment: Everything works fantastically now. Thank you again, especially for speeding up and cleaning up what I had before.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding "A" when defining the range to be copied:

```
sh.Range("A" & L & ":" & lastcolumn1 & L)
```

becomes

```
sh.Range("A" & L & ":A" & lastcolumn1 & L)
```

Comment: Gah I can't figure out line breaks... hope you can read this!  

Ah, sorry about that. I tend to use:  

    sh.Range("A" & L & ":A" & chr(64+lastcolumn1) & L)  

But this breaks if the column goes past Z.  
chr() function converts from numbers to letters - 65 becomes a, 66 becomes b, and so on. If you might go past Z, then have an if function which becomes "A" & chr(64+lastcolumn1-26) if needed

Comment: That was extremely helpful and I would not have stumbled upon that myself. Thank you so much!